# percentage change based on a variable

Tags: r

I understand the title is not very clear about what I am about to ask, but I think my examples will solve this.

I need to calculate percentage change of several variables in my dataset. To do it I use function:

```
pcchange=function(x,lag=1) c(diff(x,lag),rep(NA,lag))/x
```

Which i found on the internet. The problem is that after i applied it my data looks like this:

```
 color  shade   value   pcchange
RED LIGHT   -1.05   N/A
RED LIGHT   -1.37   0.3
RED LIGHT   -0.32   -0.8
RED LIGHT   0.87    -3.7
RED LIGHT   -0.20   -1.2
RED DARK    0.52    -3.6
RED DARK    -0.20   -1.4
RED DARK    0.64    -4.2
RED DARK    1.12    1
RED DARK    4.00    2.6
BLUE    LIGHT   0.93    -0.8
BLUE    LIGHT   0.78    -0.2
BLUE    LIGHT   -1.84   -3.3
BLUE    LIGHT   -0.50   -0.7
BLUE    LIGHT   -1.11   1.2
BLUE    DARK    -4.86   3.4
BLUE    DARK    1.11    -1.2
BLUE    DARK    0.14    -0.9
BLUE    DARK    0.12    -0.1
BLUE    DARK    -1.65   -14.5
GREEN   LIGHT   3.13    -2.9
GREEN   LIGHT   2.65    -0.2
GREEN   LIGHT   -2.36   -1.9
GREEN   LIGHT   -3.11   0.3
GREEN   LIGHT   3.49    -2.1
GREEN   DARK    1.91    -0.5
GREEN   DARK    -1.10   -1.6
GREEN   DARK    -1.93   0.8
GREEN   DARK    1.00    -1.5
GREEN   DARK    -0.23   -1.2
```

And what I am trying to accomplish is:

```
color   shade   value   pcchange
RED LIGHT   -1.05   N/A
RED LIGHT   -1.37   0.31
RED LIGHT   -0.32   -0.76
RED LIGHT   0.87    -3.69
RED LIGHT   -0.20   -1.23
RED DARK    0.52    N/A
RED DARK    -0.20   -1.39
RED DARK    0.64    -4.21
RED DARK    1.12    0.75
RED DARK    4.00    2.58
BLUE    LIGHT   0.93    N/A
BLUE    LIGHT   0.78    -0.16
BLUE    LIGHT   -1.84   -3.35
BLUE    LIGHT   -0.50   -0.73
BLUE    LIGHT   -1.11   1.21
BLUE    DARK    -4.86   N/A
BLUE    DARK    1.11    -1.23
BLUE    DARK    0.14    -0.88
BLUE    DARK    0.12    -0.11
BLUE    DARK    -1.65   -14.48
GREEN   LIGHT   3.13    N/A
GREEN   LIGHT   2.65    -0.16
GREEN   LIGHT   -2.36   -1.89
GREEN   LIGHT   -3.11   0.32
GREEN   LIGHT   3.49    -2.12
GREEN   DARK    1.91    N/A
GREEN   DARK    -1.10   -1.58
GREEN   DARK    -1.93   0.75
GREEN   DARK    1.00    -1.52
GREEN   DARK    -0.23   -1.23
```

Sorry for long examples but I want to ask my question as clear as possible.

So what you can see I need a way to make function "reset" after value in certain variable changes (in my example it would be variable:shade).

Is there simple way to do this or only solution is based on loops?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to _apply `pcchange` by group(s)_ -- see `?ave` (`ave(data$value, data$color, data$shade, FUN = pcchange)`), and generally, `?aggregate`, `?split`, `?tapply` etc

Answer (score 2):

I would put this little addition into a comment but I have not enough rep for that :)
So if you still want the NA to be placed at the beginning of each group you must change the function to look like this for example:

```
pcchange = function(x){  c( NA, diff(x)/x[-length(x)] ) }
```

As you only calculate the percentage change between consecutive values(therefore you don't have any values in between that you need to jump over) you don't need `lag` and multiple NAs at the beginning of each group. As only one NA is needed for each group, `rep` can be neglected too.

Answer (score 1):

use `dplyr`, group by the things that break the data frame, mutate:

```
data %>% group_by(color, shade) %>% mutate(pcchange = pcchange(value))
```

produces a data frame (well, actually a `tbl`) that looks like:

```
   color shade value    pcchange
1    RED LIGHT -1.05   0.3047619
2    RED LIGHT -1.37  -0.7664234
3    RED LIGHT -0.32  -3.7187500
4    RED LIGHT  0.87  -1.2298851
5    RED LIGHT -0.20          NA
6    RED  DARK  0.52  -1.3846154
7    RED  DARK -0.20  -4.2000000
8    RED  DARK  0.64   0.7500000
9    RED  DARK  1.12   2.5714286
10   RED  DARK  4.00          NA
11  BLUE LIGHT  0.93  -0.1612903
12  BLUE LIGHT  0.78  -3.3589744
13  BLUE LIGHT -1.84  -0.7282609
14  BLUE LIGHT -0.50   1.2200000
15  BLUE LIGHT -1.11          NA
16  BLUE  DARK -4.86  -1.2283951
[etc]
```

I note your answer has the NA's at the start of each sequence, but your `pcchange` function puts it at the end. Edit `pcchange` if you need that.

Expect a solution using data tables and base R (`split`) soon...

Comment: I think your solution works, could you explain me how to change it so N/A will be at the start? I need attach it later to my main dataset so it has to be correctly positioned.
What you mean by your last sentence?

Comment: @spacedman Now, there is also a `data.table` solution as you had expected.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` (development version 1.9.7) solution which is quite similar to the OP's expected results.

### Read data

But first, we need to create the data for a reproducible example. The `fread` function from `data.table` is very convenient here.

```
library(data.table)

# prepare data, reading first 3 columns
dt <- fread("color  shade   value   pcchange
RED LIGHT   -1.05   N/A
RED LIGHT   -1.37   0.3
RED LIGHT   -0.32   -0.8
RED LIGHT   0.87    -3.7
RED LIGHT   -0.20   -1.2
RED DARK    0.52    -3.6
RED DARK    -0.20   -1.4
RED DARK    0.64    -4.2
RED DARK    1.12    1
RED DARK    4.00    2.6
BLUE    LIGHT   0.93    -0.8
BLUE    LIGHT   0.78    -0.2
BLUE    LIGHT   -1.84   -3.3
BLUE    LIGHT   -0.50   -0.7
BLUE    LIGHT   -1.11   1.2
BLUE    DARK    -4.86   3.4
BLUE    DARK    1.11    -1.2
BLUE    DARK    0.14    -0.9
BLUE    DARK    0.12    -0.1
BLUE    DARK    -1.65   -14.5
GREEN   LIGHT   3.13    -2.9
GREEN   LIGHT   2.65    -0.2
GREEN   LIGHT   -2.36   -1.9
GREEN   LIGHT   -3.11   0.3
GREEN   LIGHT   3.49    -2.1
GREEN   DARK    1.91    -0.5
GREEN   DARK    -1.10   -1.6
GREEN   DARK    -1.93   0.8
GREEN   DARK    1.00    -1.5
GREEN   DARK    -0.23   -1.2",
            drop = "pcchange")
```

### Compute relative change by group

```
# Now, compute relative changes by group
dt[, pcchange := value/shift(value) - 1, by = "color,shade"]
print(dt)
    color shade value    pcchange
 1:   RED LIGHT -1.05          NA
 2:   RED LIGHT -1.37   0.3047619
 3:   RED LIGHT -0.32  -0.7664234
 4:   RED LIGHT  0.87  -3.7187500
 5:   RED LIGHT -0.20  -1.2298851
 6:   RED  DARK  0.52          NA
 7:   RED  DARK -0.20  -1.3846154
 8:   RED  DARK  0.64  -4.2000000
 9:   RED  DARK  1.12   0.7500000
10:   RED  DARK  4.00   2.5714286
11:  BLUE LIGHT  0.93          NA
12:  BLUE LIGHT  0.78  -0.1612903
13:  BLUE LIGHT -1.84  -3.3589744
14:  BLUE LIGHT -0.50  -0.7282609
15:  BLUE LIGHT -1.11   1.2200000
16:  BLUE  DARK -4.86          NA
17:  BLUE  DARK  1.11  -1.2283951
18:  BLUE  DARK  0.14  -0.8738739
19:  BLUE  DARK  0.12  -0.1428571
20:  BLUE  DARK -1.65 -14.7500000
21: GREEN LIGHT  3.13          NA
22: GREEN LIGHT  2.65  -0.1533546
23: GREEN LIGHT -2.36  -1.8905660
24: GREEN LIGHT -3.11   0.3177966
25: GREEN LIGHT  3.49  -2.1221865
26: GREEN  DARK  1.91          NA
27: GREEN  DARK -1.10  -1.5759162
28: GREEN  DARK -1.93   0.7545455
29: GREEN  DARK  1.00  -1.5181347
30: GREEN  DARK -0.23  -1.2300000
    color shade value    pcchange
```

### Explanation

1. By default, the `shift` function lags values by 1 and fills up missing values with `NA`. This conveniently returns `NA` for the first row of each group as requested by the OP.
2. The formula to compute the relative change is mathematically equivalent with less typing.
3. The parameter `by = "color,shade"` tells `data.table` to group by `color` and `shade`.
4. `print(dt)` is required here to show the result. `data.table` creates new variables *by reference* (without copying the whole object), thereby saving time and memory.